# How to add a link to call an API in swagger's API group description UI

Tags: java, api, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I am using swagger and Springfox for my API documentation. I have an html file in my server which describes all the response codes that returns from my all APIs.

I need to set a common link [Api-response-codes](https://dev.sample.com/v2/api-docs?type=response-codes) in Swagger's API group description (as shown in image) that will call an API to download the server file.

Download file API is a public access API, so no authentication or permission checks needed. It is just a link to download the file in server.

Is it possible to do so using java?

[image]